# Navigation from one page to another page with in the modal popup (not window.open) with out using iframe

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, modal-dialog

When I click on the button, the modal dialog (Bootstrap) popup was opened by using the following code:

```
    <div data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" id="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-left: -40%">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div id="modal_body"></div>
                        <a href="#"><div id="modal_next"></div></a>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                        <button id="mn" class="btn green" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Continue Task</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The dynamic content was loaded by using the `jquery.load()` function as below

```
$( "#modal_body" ).load("target file");
```

I want to navigate from the loaded page to another page when the user clicks on the links in the modal body.

But when click on the anchor link, then confirm alert (leave page and stay on page) was coming.
I don't want that alert and I don't want to use any iframes.

I just want to replace the current content with target file html content.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to override normal link behaviour somehow from navigating you normally to replacing the content.